# Using Markers in Apple MapKit while using a customized MapTiles source

Tags: ios, maps, xamarin, mapkit

I am working on an iOS application (using C# and Xamarin), which includes an Apple-MapKit-widget.
This widget does not show the map content of Apple, but a customized content (via MapTiles):

```
String urlTemplate = "http://customized-maptiles-url.example/pics/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
MKTileOverlay overlay = new MKTileOverlay(urlTemplate);
overlay.CanReplaceMapContent = true;
map.AddOverlay(overlay, MKOverlayLevel.AboveLabels);
```

This is working quite good.
Then I set the VisibleMapRect:

```
MKMapRect name = new MKMapRect(new MKMapPoint(0, 0), new MKMapSize(20000,20000));
map.SetVisibleMapRect(name, true);
```

And now I want to set a marker:

```
var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion.FromDistance(mapCenter,0,0);
var height = UIScreen.MainScreen.ApplicationFrame.Height;
var width = UIScreen.MainScreen.ApplicationFrame.Width;
map.Region = mapRegion;
var coord = map.ConvertPoint(new PointF(0,0), View);
map.SetCenterCoordinate(coord, true);
var coord2 = map.ConvertPoint(new PointF(0,0), View);
map.AddAnnotation(new MKPointAnnotation()
{
Title = "MyAnnotation",
Coordinate = coord2
});
```

This **SHOULD** set a marker, which is located in the middle of the map.
But the result is: The marker is on the middle of the screen but **when I zoom out** to see the map completely it is absolutely NOT in the middle of the map.

Can anyone help? That would be great! Thank you!

Comment: Even with custom tiles, the world is still in the same coordinate system and size (latitude -90 to +90 and longitude -180 to +180).  What does `map.ConvertPoint` do?  Is that the equivalent of `convertPoint:toCoordinateFromView:`?  See what the value of `coord2` is.

Comment: Hi @Anna, thank you for your reply! :) Here is a link by Xamarin: http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M%3AMonoTouch.MapKit.MKMapView.ConvertPoint%28System.Drawing.PointF%2CMonoTouch.UIKit.UIView%29

lat: 81,2637132730438
long: -130,000271749849

Comment: Yes, it's the equivalent of convertPoint:toCoordinateFromView: which means all you're doing is converting the top-left CGPoint that is _currently_ displayed on the map into latitude, longitude coordinates.  The coordinate 81,-130 is not the "middle" of the world.

Comment: Hi @Anna - thank you very much!! The "middle" of the map would be 0°00'00.0"N 0°00'00.0"E, right? Do you know how to convert it the right way? Thank you very much again!

Comment: There is nothing to convert.  The Coordinate property is a CLLocationCoordinate2D struct which has latitude and longitude.  Set the Coordinate to CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0,0) or explicitly as Coordinate.Latitude = 0, etc.